# Injecting Node.js into static HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, templates, express

I'm currently looking for a way to make node.js-API-calls from static html. I've looked at Express and similar template engines, however they would require me to write my html and generate it from their template engines instead of the other way around. I often get production ready HTML from designers and don't want to rewrite that to fit with express. Alternatively is there a converter from existing .html to template engines?

To get a bit more basic, I want to use node.js in a similar way to ajax, basically being able to call things like `<img onClick="someNodeFunctionWithDatabaseCalls()">` from an html-file running on node as a server and then manipulate the .html-file with DOM or something like that. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Node doesn't run in a browser, so "injecting Node.js into static HTML" doesn't make sense...

Comment: @Neal: That wasn't very helpful. I did, however it didn't help me. Else I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: @Chad: I want to basically run a node.js file that starts a webserver on a port of my choosing(which is easy), feed it a static HTML-file, which in turn contains AJAX-style node.js-calls

Comment: What is an "AJAX-style node.js-call"? That phrase doesn't make sense.

Comment: something like `<img onHover="someNodeFunction()">` in the HTML, with someNodeFunction using the full spectrum of things only AJAX or direct Node could do, like Database-calls

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Node.js is server side only; you can't just run whatever code you want wherever you want. You can on the other hand, use your choice of web socket (I would recommend socket.io), to send a request to your server, which can in turn perform any actions you want.

Comment: This is indeed exactly what I was looking for, and something I hadn't stumbled across before. Thank you for your help! If you submit this as an answer I'd be happy to give you the accepted and upvote-mark, apparently it's not possible to select comments as acceptable answers: [link]( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

Comment: @fk2 Reworded as an answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js is for server-side scripting only. In order to run node.js code in response to an event on your webpage, you will have to use websockets to send a request to your server, which can in turn run the necessary code (db requests, etc.).

As far as various web sockets go, I would recommend using socket.io; it is very simple to use, and is well known for working on many different devices. See [socket.io](http://socket.io) for more information and examples.